# $(10^k-1)\overline{a_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-k}}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $k \geq \dfrac{n}{2}$ be a positive integer and $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-k}$ be nonzero digits. Prove that $$(10^k-1)\overline{a_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-k}}=\overline{a_1a_2 \ldots a_{n-k-1}a_{n-k}' \underbrace{99 \ldots 9}_{2k-n}b_1b_2 \ldots b_{n-k-1}b_{n-k}'}$$ where $a_{n-k}' = a_{n-k}-1, b_i = 9-a_i,$ and $b_{n-k}' = 9-a_{n-k}'$.

I thought about proving this by induction, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  RHS &=
  \sum_{j=1}^{n-k-1} (a_{j} 10^{n-j}+b_{j}10^{n-k-j})+a'_{n-k} 10^{k}+
  b'_{n-k}+9\sum_{j=1}^{2k-n} 10^{k-j} \\
  &=
  \sum_{j=1}^{n-k-1} [a_{j} 10^{n-j}+(9-a_{j})10^{n-k-j}]+(a_{n-k}-1)10^{k}+
  [9-(a_{n-k}-1)]+9\sum_{j=1}^{2k-n} 10^{k-j} \\
  &=
  \sum_{j=1}^{n-k} (a_{j} 10^{n-j}-a_{j} 10^{n-k-j})+
  9\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}10^{j}-10^{k}+10 \\
  &=
  (10^{k}-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} a_{j} 10^{n-k-j}+
  (10^{k}-10)-10^{k}+10 \\
  &=
  (10^{k}-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} a_{j} 10^{n-k-j} \\
  &= LHS
\end{align*}